# How to create a legend using a vector of ints?

Tags: octave

How to create a legend using a vector of ints using Octave 4.4? I'm able to create a legend for a plot using this code:

```
legend({'4','8','16','32',}, 'location', 'northeast');
```

I don't want the list of values to be hardcoded, but I want to use a vector of ints as it may change depending on the input data:

```
v=[4,8,16,32];
```

I tried this but it creates a legend with no texts:

```
legend(cellstr(num2cell(v)), 'location', 'northeast');
```

Comment: Your conversion does not work. If you try only `cellstr(num2cell(v))` it returns a cell of empty strings. I would have used `l=arrayfun(@num2str,v,'UniformOutput',false)` to create a cell array like the one you created manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [`legend`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/legend.html):

> Legend entries may be specified as individual character string arguments, a character array, or a cell array of character strings.

The character array can be easily generated using [`num2str`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/num2str.html). You just need to pay attention, that your input (numerical) array is a column vector.

Here's a small example:

```matlab
x = 0:100;
v = [4, 8, 16, 32];

hold on;
plot(x, v(1)./x);
plot(x, v(2)./x);
plot(x, v(3)./x);
plot(x, v(4)./x);
hold off;

legend(num2str(v.'), 'location', 'northeast');
```

That'd be the output for `v = [4, 8, 16, 32]`:

[image: Output 1]

That'd be the output for `v = [2, 3, 4, 5]`:

[image: Output 2]

Hope that helps!

```
>> version
ans = 5.1.0
```